# Visual Studio doesn't remember folder collapsed/expanded state on startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Everytime I reopen a Visual Studio(17.0.5) project, all the folders are collapsed. Is there a way to fix that, so VS remembers the folder collapse/expand state of the project?

Answer (score 0):

Under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Projects and Solutions`->`General`, tick 'Restore Solution Explorer project hierarchy state on solution load' (mine is unticked for performance reasons)

[image]

Comment: Hey! It's already ticked.